# Xccy without back notional exchange

Tags: cross-currency-basis

Let’a Say i’m Trading a 1bln € EUR-USD fixed-fixed cross currency starting in 3M.
My USD notional is fixed at today’s spot.
Two cases:
- back and front notional exchange.
-Only front notional exchange.

How do their prices compare?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

A standard XCCY minus an “XCCY without back notional exchange” is a currency forward struck at today’s spot. The difference will be positive or negative depending on how the forward FX compares to the spot.

Comment: Just for my information, do these things really trade ("XCCY with front but without back notional exchange") in the marketplace ?

Comment: I don't think they do.

Comment: You could look at this as a XCCY swap + an offsetting long dated fwd FX (which don't trade), or as an IBOR leg only swap (which also dont really trade) + a spot FX